# Why does my global menu freeze in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, globalmenu

When using Ubuntu 13.10 I often get my global menu frozen.

For example if I scroll down on the volume icon (to lower the volume) the notification and the actual volume is modified 3 to 10 seconds after the action. This behavior is the same with globalmenu entries and every notification icon.

This behavior happens randomly to my eye. Everything else is working nicely and the bar is never frozen forever.
My laptop is a Asus X301A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be refering about this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1199877

The fix was already released but probably still hasn't made it to regular updates, you can enable proposed updates (software center > edit > sources) that is what I did.

Comment: I never found this because I've never searched for "unity-panel-service". I've installed the update, rebooted and the problem looks solved (tested with the "GIMP issue"), the menu bar is way more responsive. Thanks !